# Total open Qty for an Item

Tags: microsoft-excel, powerpivot

i have a table of open Purchase orders with multiple PO, an item can appear a number of times on any PO.

i then have a separate table for items that i am looking to buy but i want to know how many i have on order currently.

is there a DAX way to do this, i am trying to bring this value into one table using the Related function?

i have tried a number of diffent combinations but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0):

i think i have solved it

`=CALCULATE(SUM(TABLEOPENPO[po_open_quantity]),FILTER(TABLEOPENPO,TABLEOPENPO[item_id]=TABLE[item_id]))`

seems to work any how